# Why SwiftUI view transitions modifiers don't work?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I needed to add a view to my scene using a view transition. I was trying to use the modifier `.transition(.opacity)` but it just adds the view without any transition. I also tried the other transition types and they don't work. Since this is a really simple test project a don't see where's the issue. Here's a link to a [video of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFRXe.gif)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {

    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {self.show.toggle()}) {
                Text("Button")
            }

            if show {
                Text("Test Text")
                    .transition(.move(edge: .top))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add animation for the transition

```
 if show {

                Text("Test Text").animation(.linear)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
        }
```

Comment: Thanks now it works. I have used transitions before but I didn't have to set an animation modifier, did something change?

Comment: I have no idea. It may depend on the views.