# Why Navigate Back Go to First View in SwiftUI with List and Section?

Tags: navigation, swiftui

In SecondView, Back Button Go Home View. Should be back First Button. I didn't understand why?

```
HomeView
    //Home
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                    List {
                        Section(header: Text(verbatim: "First".localized())) {
                                NavigationLink(destination: FirstView()
                                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"), displayMode: .large)
                                ) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "square.stack.3d.up")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                                            .padding(.trailing, 6)
                                        Text("Test")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home Page"),displayMode: .large)
                }
            }
```

FirstView

```
FirstView
//...body
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) { Text("Second View") } )
```

SecondView

```
SecondView
//In here navigationback button go home page
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095039/swiftui-navigationview-going-back-if-navigationlink-is-inside-a-navigationbarit?

Comment: I dont have NavigationView in SecondView because I have the first one.

Comment: Did you read carefully? It is about NavigationLink usage issue in navigationBarItems.