# Return from NavigationLink after Alert shown

Tags: swiftui

I am "pushing" a new view using `NavigationLink` like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: SomeView(shown: $isActive)), isActive: $isActive) { ... }
```

Inside `SomeView` i can now set `shown` to `false` to "pop" back. This works.

However, if show an Alert inside `SomeView` this no longer works. When showing the alert I also get this error message in the console:

```
popToViewController:transition: called on <_TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext_ 0x7ffc1e858c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's how I am showing the alert inside `SomeView`:

```
VStack
{
// ...
}
.alert(isPresented:$showAlert)
{
    Alert(title: Text("Some text"), message: Text("More text"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
}
```

I show the alert by setting `showAlert` to true.

Answer (score 0):

Or do you have/ want to do it your way with the `@Binding`?
Or this method of navigating between the views and option?
[SwiftUI pop view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513568/ios-swiftui-pop-or-dismiss-view-programmatically)

If so this code works perfectly fine without any error
Tested on iOS 13.6

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) {
                Text("Go to child")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SomeView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            
            Text("I'm the child and if you press me an alert is comming up")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showAlert.toggle()
                }
            
            Text("Go Back")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            
        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert)
            {
                Alert(title: Text("Some text"), message: Text("More text"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the binding way was the proper way, and someone helps me figure out my problem. But your sample works well, although I do get another warning in the console: TestPushPop[35996:2063035] [UIContextMenuInteraction] Attempting -[UIContextMenuInteraction dismissMenu], when not in an active state. This is a client error most often caused by calling dismiss more than once during a given lifecycle. (<_UIVariableGestureContextMenuInteraction: 0x600003577480>) - not sure if this is a completely different matter.