# Can you access @Environment values in a custom struct initializer in Swift/SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, environment, init

I've been trying to implement a custom back button according to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571349/custom-back-button-for-navigationviews-navigation-bar-in-swiftui). Seems as though [most common response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513568/ios-swiftui-pop-or-dismiss-view-programmatically) in how to dismiss a NavigationLink is through accessing the @Environment value presentationMode through:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
```

And then calling dismiss Method in a custom button struct:

```
var btnBack : some View { Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
            Image("ic_back") // set image here
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                Text("Go back")
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to access the presentationMode var in a custom initializer in a struct? I've tried things like:

```
init(var: Variable) {
        self.presentationMode = @Environment(\.presentationMode)
        self.var = var
}
```

or:

```
var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

init(var: Variable) {
        presentationMode = @Environment(\.presentationMode)
        self.var = var
}
```

or (with dismiss action per [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss)):

```
init(var: Variable) {
        @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
        self.var = var
}
```

The above seems to initialize, but can't find dismiss in scope. New to iOS/Swift & not sure this is possible, but appreciate any guidance!

Comment: No, the SwiftUI wrappers only work at `struct`/ `class` level and aren't available until after the initializer has run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't access the environment in the initializer, but that's not necessary. You can access the environment values without assigning them to your View struct.

```
struct ButtonBack: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.dismiss) {
            // some View
        }
    }

    private func dismiss() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```