# How to close a Split NavigationView on request in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on an iPad app where I will have three views inside a single `NavigationView` to provide the 3-way split screen found in native apps (Notes) on horizontal mode. See the screenshot below as an example.

[image]

A particular behaviour that I found to be interesting is when I click on an item in the `Folders` View. The entire `Folders` View collapses to the side when I do. See the following gif for an example of the behaviour that I found to be eyecatching (Here, I press on the `React native` Item).

[image]

I want to replicate this behaviour using SwiftUIs `NavigationView` but haven't managed to so far. I've tried many solutions in [this thread about closing/popping a View in the navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513568/ios-swiftui-pop-or-dismiss-view-programmatically), but none of them works.

You can find the code I have prepared below with a gif representing how it looks as of now

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Close First") {
                    // Close the View
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("First")

            Text("Second")
                .navigationTitle("Second")

            Text("Third")
                .navigationTitle("Third")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPad mini (6th generation)")
.previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

GUI:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, TIA.

Comment: This looks like a bug - dismiss should work in this case.

Comment: I also noticed if you select a NavigationLink in the middle column it doesn't close the sidebar unless you had chosen a different NavigationLink in the first column  I think we just have to keep submitting bug reports.

Comment: Yea, I have submitted a bug report in this regard.