# Presence of @Environment dismiss causes list to constantly rebuild its content on scrolling

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to build a list of TextFields where each field is associated with focus id, so that I can auto scroll to such a text field when it receives focus. In reality the real app is a bit more complex which also includes TextEditors and many other controls.

Now, I found out that if my view defines `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` then the list is rebuilding all the time during manual scrolling. If I just comment out the line `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` then there is no rebuilding of the list when I scroll. Obviously, I want to be able to dismiss my view when user clicks some button. In the real app it's even worse: during scrolling everything is lagging, I cannot get smooth scrolling. And my list is not huge it's just 10 items or so.

Here is a demo example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                DismissListView()
            } label: {
                Text("Go to see the list")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DismissListView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case line(Int)
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focus: Field?
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                let _ = print("body is rebuilding")
                
                Button("Dismiss me") {
                    dismiss()
                }
                
                Section("Section") {
                    ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {num in
                        TextField("text", text: $text)
                            .id(Field.line(num))
                            .focused($focus, equals: .line(num))
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            .onChange(of: focus) {_ in
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(focus, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The questions are:

- Why is the list rebuilding during manual back and forth scrolling when `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` is defined, and the same is NOT happening when dismiss is NOT defined?
- Is there any workaround for this: I need to be able to use ScrollProxyReader to focus any text field when the focus changes, and I need to be able to dismiss the view, but in the same time I need to avoid constant rebuilds of the list during scrolling, because it drops app performance and scrolling becomes jagged...

P.S. Demo app constantly outputs "body is rebuilding" when dismiss is defined and the list is scrolled, but if any text field gets a focus manually, then the "body is rebuilding" is not printed anymore even if the dismiss is still defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I could make an assumption, but that would be really rather a guess (based on experience, observations, etc). In a fact, all **WHYs** like "why this sh... (bug) happens" should be asked on https://developer.apple.com/forums/ (there are Apple's engineers there) or reported to https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/
2. A solution is to separate `dismiss` depenent part into dedicated view, so hiding it from parent body (and so do not affect it)

```
    struct DismissView: View {
        // visible only for this view !!
        @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

        var body: some View {
            Button("Dismiss me") {
                // affects current context, so it does not matter
                // in which sub-view is called
                dismiss()           
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                let _ = print("body is rebuilding")
                DismissView()   // << here !!

    // ... other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I came across this bug with

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
```

issue too and declaring it just private didn't fix it.

However, even though Xcode says some of the methods/code is deprecated as you type this, this solution posted below works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279591/1035899

So basically it is using `presentationMode` instead of `dismiss`.

For my case, I couldn't use a DismissView() as the selected answer because I didn't want to add another UI element. I'm dismissing a view (popping the nav stack) when the user taps on a TabItem in a TabView.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a weird issue that is similar to this issue but a bit more problematic.

Adding `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` in combination with `@FocusState` in child views caused the screen to infinitely redraw and lock up the app. If I remove the `@Environment` the view works perfectly. This means that I have to either rework an entire view that is otherwise fully functional to try and figure out why adding @Environment breaks it, or come up with a work around for dismissing the view.

This is not the ideal solution, but if you get stuck in a similar way, here's how I was able to work around it:

**Create a UINavigationController extension and assign the navigation controller to a global variable**

```
var navController: UINavigationController? = nil
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navController = self
    }
}
```

Call `navController?.popViewController(animated: false)` when you need to dismiss the view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and could fix it by **not** using the view's initialiser to initialise the @StateObject.

That means I **removed**

```
init(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
   self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
}
```

Then, the view was not stuck in an infinite loading loop anymore.
More info about this: https://www.swiftcraft.io/articles/how-to-initialize-state-inside-the-views-init-